# JQuery - Como posso obter texto dentro do <p> e alterar

Tags: jquery

Quero alterar o texto dentro do `<p>` mas sem o JQuery consultar classe ou ID somente o texto.
Tentei fazer algo com esse mas ele consulta a class no `<p>`

```js
$('p.text').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace($.trim($('p.text').text()),'Forte Max');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <p class="text">Forte '.$N.'</p>
```

Como eu uso o `<p>Forte '.$N.'</p>` o número final consta como `Forte 15` Então gostaria que o JQuery identificasse o Texto e mudasse para `Forte Max`

Comment: De onde vem `$N`? Não era mais fácil alterar a lógica que atribui o valor ou impressão deste?

Comment: Sim eu já tentei fazer isso mas não deu certo, o $N é a numeração de cada nível atribuído ao item. Por exemplo eu poderia ir até o Forte 15 e alterar para Max mas é com numeração então quis fazer isso de outro jeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você quer substituir o texto `Forte 15` por `Forte Max` dentro de um parágrafo `<p>` qualquer, certo?

O seguinte código fará isso. Mas **tenha atenção**, pois se a string que desejas modificar aparecer em vários parágrafos diferentes, em **todos elementos** `<p>` acontecerá esta modificação **na primeira ocorrência dessa string**.

```
$("p").text(function(index, modificador) {
    return modificador.replace("Forte 15", "Forte Max");
});
```

Agora, se você quiser que a string seja substituída **em todos elementos** `<p>` da página **e em todas ocorrências dentro daquele mesmo elemento** (diferente do código que descrevi anteriormente, que só substituirá a primeira ocorrência de cada parágrafo), então adote a seguinte solução:

```
$("p").text(function(index, modificador) {
    return modificador.replace(/Forte 15/g, "Forte Max");
});
```

Note que aqui a sintaxe muda um pouco e a "string velha" aparece entre barras. É assim mesmo. Depois vem uma letra `g`.

Este `g` significa "global".

Comment: Tem apenas um string com a descrição de Forte 15 então ela vai mudar um paragrafo enfim. Se colocar por classe também e identificar o texto talvez ajudasse quem quisesse identificar o texto somente naquela class. Bem muito obrigado Melhor Resposta!

Answer (score 0):

A propriedade textContent da interface Node representa o conteúdo de texto de um nó e dos seus descendentes. textContent retorna todos os elementos de um nó. Por outro lado, o  innerText é ciente da estilização e não retorna elementos de texto "escondidos".

```js
    let text = document.getElementById('alteracao').textContent;
    console.log(text); // Agora a variável de texto é: 'Forte '.$N.'
    let novotext = document.getElementById('alteracao').textContent = 'Forte Max';
    console.log(novotext);  // O HTML de text agora é: <p class="text" id="alteracao">Forte Max</p>
```

```html
<p class="text" id="alteracao">Forte '.$N.'</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar mas vou ser mais claro. `$N` identifica o número dentro do SQL, ou seja o número final vai ser "Forte 15". No HTML  inspecionando vai ficar `<p>Forte 15</p>`, então por isso quero que ele identifique o texto dentro `<p>` que é `<p>Forte 15</p>` e altere para `<p>Forte Max</p>`.